# Drawing pedigrees with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I'm using a package called `pst-pdgr` which uses `PSTricks`. I have no prior experience with `PSTricks` but I am trying to read and understand as I go. However, I've run into a problem while compiling the pedigree: it doesn't render! I am following the documentation that came with `pst-pdgr`, but nothing I do--adding whatever packages I think are necessary (because the documentation doesn't go into much detail)--are fixing it. Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-pdgr,pstricks,pst-pdf,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left=2cm, bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(7,7)
\rput{0.5,1.5}{\pstPerson[affected,female]{A}}
\rput{0.5,1.5}{\pstPerson[male]{B}}
\pstRelationship[descentnode=AB]{A}{B}
\ncline{AB}{C}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The coordinate arguments of `\rput` should be in parentheses () *not* braces {}. Also you need to compile this with `latex+dvips` not `pdflatex`.

Comment: Yes, the coordinates aren't suppose to be in curly braces (how stupid of me!). I'm going to fix that and compile with `latex+dvips` and see it that works.

Comment: If you use latex+dvips, do not use pst-pdf.  It is for pdflatex route.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent nearly a whole day on this, I finally found a solution: compiling with XeLaTeX to PDF. Not only did it render my pedigree beautifully, but the accompanying text as well, which I had not added to MWE. Thanks to Alann Munn and Boris who gave me pointers, because I was thinking my code was all wrong when really it was the compiling.